# Restrict jstree dragging from one tree to other tree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using Two different trees

> - Tree1
>
>   - A
>   - B
>   - C
> - Tree2
>
>   - A1
>   - B1
>   - C1

I am using drag and drop for both within the tree and i want to restrict that dragging from Tree1 to Tree2

> $('#tree1').on('move_node.jstree',function(event,data){
>              });

How can I allow a tree to drag only within the tree

Pls help to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to restrict the DND Plugin in jstree get the Latest source from [github](https://github.com/vakata/jstree)
place this in [check_callback](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=check_callback&f=%24.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback)

```
check_callback : function (o, n, p, pos, more) {
  if(more && more.dnd && more.is_multi) { return false; }
  return true;
}
```